# How to pin UIView to the bottom of UIScrollView in Storyboard?

Tags: ios, xcode, uiscrollview

This is what I have:

[image]

But all I need to achieve is:

[image]

So the **facebook and register** buttons should be always at the very bottom of `UIScrollView`.

**What constraints or views should I add and where?**

Answer (score 2):

I think this will help you. You need give the constrains manually. See in image.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/OfUqH.png

Answer (score 0):

If you need those two elements at the very bottom of your *scene* you have two options, both require setting constraints directly in Interface Builder so you won't have to do this programmatically.

1. Using constraints from the `Bottom Edges` making sure to center both elements vertically and defining a with and height to your Facebook signup button
2. Using a `Stack View` that groups Facebook button and SignUp label and then defining a constraint from the bottom edges. In this case you'll want to make sure to center vertically your Stack View as well.

Remove your constraint between the Facebook button and the Forgot Password view to avoid positioning the final buttons depending on how many 'pixels' the upper elements take: you want the Facebook and Signup positioned from the bottom in an *absolute* way.

Comment: Thx for your reply, but actually I forgot to mention about one thing. If there is not enough space on the screen (horizontal iPhone), then the facebook button should be once below forgot password button. Is it possible to do thin in such case?

Comment: @BartłomiejSemańczyk in that case the underlying concept is still valid, you'll have to play a little bit more with anchoring your two views in the most non ambiguous way possible: sometimes the *Add Missing Constraints* works well. Anyway if you're considering to display this scene on an horizontal iPhone I suggest you to rearrange the whole UI with Size Classes, this will end in a much improved user experience since you'll avoid to scroll a lot.

Comment: It is with Size Classes, but still need there view pinned to the bottom. Add misding constraints doesnt work. So I think I need to setip this "facebook" button once after "forgot".  This will work. But posdible solution for my scenario would be very nice to know.